# Firebase StorageException has occurred. Code: -13000 HttpResult: 400

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Before starting explaining my problem, i'll show you the full image of my error.

[image: the android studio screen when the error occured]

I did my best to find the solution and the reason why this error would happen.

I found a few sources such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866315/storageexception-code-13000-httpresult-0-while-uploading-file-to-firebase) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881554/firebase-image-upload-issue).

I'm afraid you guys would think that my question is the same as those questions, but I think that there are some differences, so i really hope you guys read my question.

First, I have followed the official chat app tutorial by Google. ([this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#7))

and I just copied the source codes, but the error occured on chapter 8(Send Message). And there were no problems when i send the message just with texts, but problem occured when i send the message with image file from my local storage. And i just found the source that says 'In the google firebase this type of StorageException are commonly caused because of wrong StorageReference reference.', so I looked my source codes about StorageReference. But i couldn't understand that answer and I couldn't find any problems.

Second, I showed you more detail about the error message and i'll show you my full source code of MainActivity.

```java
package com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.firebase.ui.database.SnapshotParser;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.appinvite.AppInvite;
import com.google.android.gms.appinvite.AppInviteInvitation;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig;
import com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.FirebaseAppIndex;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.FirebaseUserActions;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.Indexable;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.builders.Indexables;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.builders.PersonBuilder;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView messageTextView;
        ImageView messageImageView;
        TextView messengerTextView;
        CircleImageView messengerImageView;

        public MessageViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            messageTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
            messageImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageImageView);
            messengerTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messengerTextView);
            messengerImageView = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messengerImageView);
        }

        public void bind(FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage){
            messageTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getText());
            messageTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            messageImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public static final String MESSAGES_CHILD = "messages";
    private static final int REQUEST_INVITE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE = 2;
    private static final String LOADING_IMAGE_URL = "https://www.google.com/images/spin-32.gif";
    public static final int DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT = 10;
    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    private static final String MESSAGE_SENT_EVENT = "message_sent";
    private String mUsername;
    private String mPhotoUrl;
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final String MESSAGE_URL = "http://friendlychat.firebase.google.com/message/";

    private Button mSendButton;
    private RecyclerView mMessageRecyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private EditText mMessageEditText;
    private ImageView mAddMessageImageView;

    // Firebase instance variables
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage, MessageViewHolder> mFirebaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        // Set default username is anonymous.
        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;

        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(mFirebaseUser == null){
            // Not signed in, launch the Sign In activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        }
        else {
            mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
            if(mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() != null){
                mPhotoUrl = mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            }
        }
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
                .build();


        // Initialize ProgressBar and RecyclerView.
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mMessageRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messageRecyclerView);
        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
//        mLinearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mMessageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

        mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(mSharedPreferences
                .getInt(CodelabPreferences.FRIENDLY_MSG_LENGTH, DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT))});
        mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });

        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Send messages on click.
                FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(),
                        mUsername,
                        mPhotoUrl,
                        null);
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD)
                        .push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                mMessageEditText.setText("");
            }
        });

        mAddMessageImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addMessageImageView);
        mAddMessageImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Select image for image message on click.
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        // New child entries
        mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        SnapshotParser<FriendlyMessage> parser = new SnapshotParser<FriendlyMessage>() {
            @Override
            public FriendlyMessage parseSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(FriendlyMessage.class);
                if(friendlyMessage != null){
                    friendlyMessage.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                }
                return friendlyMessage;
            }
        };
        DatabaseReference messageRef = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD);
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<FriendlyMessage> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<FriendlyMessage>()
                        .setQuery(messageRef, parser)
                        .build();
        mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage, MessageViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                return new MessageViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_message, parent, false));
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder holder, int position, FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                if(friendlyMessage.getText() != null){
                    holder.bind(friendlyMessage);
                }
                else {
                    String imageUrl = friendlyMessage.getImageUrl();
                    if(imageUrl.startsWith("gs://")) {
                        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                                .getReferenceFromUrl(imageUrl);
                        storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(
                                new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                            String downloadUrl= task.getResult().toString();
                                            Glide.with(holder.messageImageView.getContext())
                                                    .load(downloadUrl)
                                                    .into(holder.messageImageView);
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            Log.w(TAG, "Getting download url was not seccessful.",
                                                    task.getException());
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                        );
                    }
                    else {
                        Glide.with(holder.messageImageView.getContext())
                                .load(friendlyMessage.getImageUrl())
                                .into(holder.messageImageView);

                    }

                    holder.messageImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    holder.messageTextView.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
                }

                holder.messengerTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getName());
                if(friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl() == null){
                    holder.messengerImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this,
                            R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_36dp));
                }
                else {
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                            .load(friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl())
                            .into(holder.messengerImageView);
                }
            }
        };

        mFirebaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                int friendlyMessageCount = mFirebaseAdapter.getItemCount();
                int lastVisiblePosotion =
                        mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if(lastVisiblePosotion == -1 ||
                        (positionStart >= (friendlyMessageCount - 1) && lastVisiblePosotion == (positionStart - 1))){
                    mMessageRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
                }
            }
        });

        mMessageRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: requestCode=" + requestCode + ", resultCode=" + resultCode);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    final Uri uri = data.getData();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());

                    FriendlyMessage tempMessage = new FriendlyMessage(null, mUsername, mPhotoUrl,
                            LOADING_IMAGE_URL);
                    mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).push()
                            .setValue(tempMessage, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError,
                                                       DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                                    if (databaseError == null) {
                                        String key = databaseReference.getKey();
                                        StorageReference storageReference =
                                                FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                                                        .getReference(mFirebaseUser.getUid())
                                                        .child(key)
                                                        .child( uri.getLastPathSegment());

                                        putImageInStorage(storageReference, uri, key);
                                    } else {
                                        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to write message to database.",
                                                databaseError.toException());
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void putImageInStorage(StorageReference storageReference, Uri uri, final String key) {
        storageReference.putFile(uri).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this,
                new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage =
                                    new FriendlyMessage(null, mUsername, mPhotoUrl,
                                            task.getResult().getMetadata().getDownloadUrl()
                                                    .toString());
                            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).child(key)
                                    .setValue(friendlyMessage);
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Image upload task was not successful.",
                                    task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in.
        // TODO: Add code to check if user is signed in.
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mFirebaseAdapter.stopListening();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mFirebaseAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.sign_out_menu:
                mFirebaseAuth.signOut();
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
                mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I think I have no problems with Firebase authentication and the intallation or the version of Google Play Service.

[image: Google Play Service]

[image: Firebase Authentication]

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: are u sure the image will start with gs if(imageUrl.startsWith("gs://")) {?

Comment: hmm.. Actually I'm not sure but there were no problems when I added that code. I think that code is the one about  profile image which appears on the side of each of message texts. And I just added that code on chapter 6 and it works well. I got problems after I added codes about uploading images from local storage.

Comment: so inside this method you mean putImageInStorage? Are you getting `image upload task was not successful` in the log?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I think it was better if i explain that part..

Comment: what is the exception you are getting from `task.getException()?

Comment: I've been trying to add the screenshot of that exception, but I can't edit my question because stackoverflow says me 'Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code'. So I'll tell you in text.

Comment: com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzchw(Unknown Source:10)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzcid(Unknown Source:3)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzcie(Unknown Source:19)